# Ricci Scalar of a given diagonal metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature

Given that $$ds² = c²dt² - A(r)dr² - r²(d \theta ² + \sin²({\theta})d \phi ²).$$
I can easily find the metric for this particular situation.
But the question is: how do you find the Ricci scalar for this given metric?

Intuitively I would think the Ricci scalar is zero (like in the Schwarzschild Metric), but I'm not even sure if this is correct.
I think there should be a really easy way to calculate this, but all I can find is writing the Ricci tensor with Christoffel symbols. But writing this out seems very long... Any ideas?

Comment: You will want to look here. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/183205/calculating-christoffel-symbols-from-lagrangian

Comment: And here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694419/calculating-christoffel-symbols-using-variational-geodesic-equation

Comment: Possibly useful: https://pages.pomona.edu/~tmoore/grw/Resources/DiagMetricb.pdf from Tom Moore's site: https://pages.pomona.edu/~tmoore/grw/resources.html

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty straightforward to write some simple Mathematica code for this. And it would in any case be useful for you if you have to do this kind of calculation more than once. In any case, this would be the result
$$R=-\frac{2 \left(r a'+a^2-a\right)}{r^2 a^2}$$

Comment: To add up on this, I cannot recommend enough the open-source Python-based SageMath code (current version: 9.4). The combination of jupyter-(lab/notebook) with Sage provides for quite a pleasant workflow.

Comment: @Oбжорoв, are your sure of your formula? I have calculated $R=-(ra'+4a^{2}-4a)/(r^{2}a^{2})$

Comment: @JanGogolin I double checked an do have a factor 2 in the numerator. I have used my code before and it seems correct?

Comment: @Oбжорoв, I did the same but came to the same (mine) result. Would you mind to write down explicit your expression for $p$ and $\varepsilon$ functions?

Comment: @JanGogolin I just calculated the connections etc. Didn't make any assumptions on the energy-momentum tensor. Some intermediate results $\Gamma^r_{rr} = a'/2a$, $\Gamma^\theta_{\phi\phi} = -\cos\theta \sin\theta$ and $R^{\theta}_{\;\;\phi\theta\phi}= (a-1) \sin^2\theta/a$

Comment: The software you suggest is good. But the first few times you calculate R you should do it by hand. Especially in a situation with so much symmetry such that most of the $\Gamma$ terms are zero.

Answer (score 0):

The metric being diagonal (in some co-ordinates) doesn't sound like enough to take any sort of shortcut. But *maximally symmetric spaces* (like dS, AdS or their Riemannian counterparts) satisfy
$$
R_{abcd} = g_{ad}g_{bc} - g_{ac}g_{bd}.
$$
Another useful fact is that Ricci scalars add for direct product manifolds.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming stress-energy tensor ${\rm{T}}_{\mu}^{\nu}\equiv {\rm{diag}}~\{\varepsilon,-p,-p,-p\}$ and taking trace from both sides of Einstein field equations (EFE) one obtains the relation
\begin{equation}
-R=\kappa~(\varepsilon-3 p). \tag{1}
\end{equation}
If you know your metric component $g_{rr}$, and $g_{00}$ is constant, you can easily calculate the energy density and pressure from equations
\begin{equation}\label{pressure}
\kappa~ p=-\frac{1-{A}^{-1}}{r^2}~,\tag{2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\label{density}
\kappa~\varepsilon=\frac{1-{A}^{-1}}{r^2}-\frac{1}{r}~\frac{{\rm d}{A}^{-1}}{{\rm d}r}~,\tag{3}
\end{equation}
and insert them into equation (1).
For more detailed answer, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/679431/281096 (be aware of other notation there).

However, the assumption that $g_{00}$ is constant implies (Einstein field equations) that \begin{equation}
\label{em2l}
A(r)=\frac{1}{1-b r^{2}},\tag{4}
\end{equation}
where $b$ is some constant of dimension $L^{-2}$. As result of the equations (1),(2) and (3), the scalar Ricci curvature, pressure and energy density are constant too:
\begin{equation}
\varepsilon=3~b,~~~p=-b,~~~R=-6~b.\tag{5}
\end{equation}
Your metric describes homogeneous, static and isotropic solution derived by Einstein in 1917 called later Einstein's universe, see https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/83001/ .